# Display "excl. VAT" in Woocommerce product-subtotal

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

in Woocommerce when you choose to display prices during checkout inclusive VAT, Woocommerce then adds a `.tax_label` after the `td.product-subtotal`, and a `.includes_tax`  after the total. For customers from countries with 0% VAT, nothing is displayed, I need the tax_label and includes_tax to be displayed though as “excl. VAT”. So in the td.product-subtotal cell there should be the subtotal price with the added "excl. VAT" and in the order-total.td there should be the total price also with the added "excl.VAT".

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_hide_zero_taxes', '__return_false' );
```

Above filter does not do what I want because it does not add "excl.VAT" to the td.product-subtotal.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the cart subtotal there is a filter for that `woocommerce_cart_subtotal`.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 10, 3 );
function filter_woocommerce_cart_subtotal( $cart_subtotal, $compound, $instance ) {
  if( ! empty( $cart_subtotal ) ) {
    return $cart_subtotal . ' - excl. VAT';
  };
}; ?>
```

Untested but should be working.

Comment: @amainediary This displays it even for countries where tax is not 0%....but I actually got it to work with  if ($cart->get_subtotal_tax() == 0) . Now I still need to display this in the order-total cell though. Do you know if there is a filter, too?